# Переходы между Activity

Tags: android

Существует 2 активити. Допустим пользователь перешел с 1 активности на 2. В коде при переходе с 1 активности на 2 мы используем `startActivity`, после чего в 1 активности вызываются методы(самим android'ом, т.е. не я их вызываю) `onPause`, `onStop`, а во 2 активности методы `onCreate`, `onStart` и `onResume`.
Как вернуться на 1 активити, чтобы при этом android не вызывал метод `onCreate`?
Т.к. при вызове со 2 активности метода `startActivity`, android начинает вызовы методов `onPause`, `onStop` для 2 активности, а в 1 активности методы `onCreate`, `onStart` и `onResume`.

Comment: Напишите почему вам нужно именно такое поведение. Быть может ваш подход не очень верен?

Comment: При таких действиях всегда будет вызываться `onCreate()`. Для чего вам надо его не вызывать ?

Comment: Это все нужно, чтобы миновать очередное создание всех элементов активности и просто, чтобы активность не тратила время на их создание, а показала те что уже были созданы

Comment: Андроид сам хорошо разруливат такие ситуации. Если можно - он держит в памяти активити. Но вполне реальная ситуация, когда памяти в обрез. И тогда, что бы создать новую активити, нужно подчистить память. А это можно сделать удалением старой.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно завершить вторую `Activity` методом `finish()`. Это описано в любом начальном курсе уроков по Android разработке.

Comment: я думаю, что это не поможет. Андроид в любом случае вызовет onCreate для первой активити, если он успел ее прибить.

Comment: Если вызвать finish(), тогда к методам onPause, onStop добавится ещё метод onDestroy(), а создаваемая активность все равно будет запускать методы onCreate, onStart и onResume

Comment: @Inventor Все верно ответили - во второй активити нужно вызвать `finish()` с тогда просто обратно развернется предыдущая. `startActivity()` во второй не нужен.

Comment: @Inventor есть такая штука, как стек активити. Каждая новая открыввается поверх предыдущей. И если предыдущая не завершилась, то при завершении новой она восстановится с onResume и onStart

Answer (score 0):

Проведен эксперимент. Вторая активити по нажатию на кнопку запускает finish(). Вот она:

```
 public class SecondActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
            Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
            button.setOnClickListener(this);
```

`}

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button2:
                finish();
                break;
        }
    }
}`

Порядок запуска методов в первой активити:

05-08 15:06:35.499  19557-19557/com.android.mytestapplication D/Android :﹕ The **onCreate()** event

05-08 15:06:35.499  19557-19557/com.android.mytestapplication D/Android :﹕ The **onStart()** event

05-08 15:06:35.499  19557-19557/com.android.mytestapplication D/Android :﹕ The **onResume()** event

05-08 15:06:59.249  19557-19557/com.android.mytestapplication D/Android :﹕ The **onPause()** event

05-08 15:06:59.329  19557-19557/com.android.mytestapplication D/Android :﹕ The **onStop()** event

05-08 15:07:04.979  19557-19557/com.android.mytestapplication D/Android :﹕ The **onStart()** event

05-08 15:07:04.979  19557-19557/com.android.mytestapplication D/Android :﹕ The **onResume()** event

Результаты подтверждают верность совета metalurgus и замечания anber.

Comment: Они ничего не подтверждают. Просто приложение маленькое, активити небольшие, а памяти достаточно. Если обе активити будут побольше, памяти на устройстве поменьше, то пока видна вторая активити, система спокойно может прибить первую. И тогда, когда вторая завершится - первую придется создать.

Comment: А если у нас не 2 активности, а 3 или больше, как запустить 1 активность из 3-ей или 4-ой, минуя вызова onCreate в 1-ой активности.

Comment: Закрывать с помощью finish() все активность между первой и той, из которой нужно вызвать первую, для того, чтобы в стеке они оказались рядом. Но если акивность убита из-за нехватки памяти ее придется создавать с помощью onCreate().

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, самым простым способом здесь будет ввести переменную типа `boolean`  и запускать `onCreate` только если эта переменная - `true`.  По умолчанию присвоить `true` и в `onCreate`, перед запуском второй активити, перезаписывать её на `false` .Определить её надо в отдельном классе, что-то вроде `Utils`

Comment: вот только незадача в том, что `onCreate` запускает система, а не программист.

Comment: Но можно запускать пустой onCreate. От этого ничего не изменится @KoVadim

Comment: я понимаю, что Вы хотите сделать костыль, но во первых, вопрошающий не это хочет, а во вторых, лишняя глобальная переменная не нужна.
Также, если пользователь свернул приложение, а потом через какое то время развернул, приложение может быть перестартовано (переменная будет видимо опять обнулена), но для пользователя - нет. Возникает неувязка.

Answer (score 0):

Получается, что как ни крути, если android решил освободить память, он завершит не используемые активности и в любом случае приложение при переходе на необходимую активность вызовется метод onCreate и заного создадутся все элементы этой активности.

Comment: Не нужно создавать новый ответ, просто отредактируйте свой вопрос